# Mongoose password validation shows password in the message

Tags: express, mongoose, mern

I have a mongoose user schema, where I defined the password such that it must be of length between 6 and 12 characters like so

```
const userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
      ...
      password: {
          type: String,
          required: ['true', 'Password must be of length between 6 and 12 characters'],
          minLength: 6,
          maxLength: 12
      },
     ...
})
```

In the user registration controller, I check if there is an error before creating a user like so

```
await User.findOne({ email }, async (err1, foundUser) => {
    if (err1) {
      console.log(err1);
      next(err1);
    } else if (foundUser) {
      res.status(400);
      next(new Error('User already exists'));
    } else {
      await User.create(req.body, (err2, newUser) => {
        if (err2) {
          console.log(err2.errors);
          next(err2);
        } else {
          res.json({
            _id: newUser._id,
            name: newUser.name,
            email: newUser.email,
            token: generateWebToken(newUser._id),
          });
        }
      });
    }
```

The errors are caught by an errorHandler middleware where it return a json object with the `message` property set to `err.message`.

The issue I have is that in the front end when a user tries to register with a password that doesn't meet the requirements, the entered password is shown in plain text in the error message received from the backend validation. How can I hide the entered password from the message from the backend (not from the frontend)?

Comment: Please validates the password length before attempting to save the user object in db. 
By this you have control on messages.
Don't save `req.body` directly in db. Validates the params and then save in db.

Comment: But that's what I do! If the required conditions are not met, an error is passed and the controller exit without saving the data into the database!!